# Which is best way to get CBServices and CBCharacteristic in swift BLE?

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy

Some times cbcharacteristic value is null while connect. Please help for solve this type of problem in swift 3. Best structure to arrange all services and its characteristics.

```
func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverServices error: Error?)
{ 
    if let er = error{
        print(er)
        return
    }

    if let services = peripheral.services as [CBService]!{
        for service in services{

            peripheral.discoverCharacteristics(nil, for: service)
        }
    }
}

func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?){

    if let arraychar = service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]!{

        for getCharacteristic in arraychar{    
        arrayValue.append(String(data: dd, encoding: String.Encoding.ascii)!)
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please elaborate your question. Add some code, so that easy for anyone to help.

Comment: i have above code for get all data, if anyone has better code for this then tell me, so i can use in app, thanks.

Comment: Your code looks fine up until the `arrayValue.append(String ...` bit. That makes no sense.

Comment: You need to call `readValue(for characteristic:)`, in your case when you discover the characteristic.

Comment: Thanks. can you give me sample for this.

Comment: @Paulw11 if you dont know ans then wait and watch for another replies of ans. And ans is readValue() was forgot to add my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, didDiscoverCharacteristicsFor service: CBService, error: Error?) {

    self.dictSerivesCharacteistic.setObject(service.characteristics!, forKey: service.uuid.uuidString as NSCopying)


    for newChar: CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics!{

        peripheral.readValue(for: newChar)

        if newChar.properties.rawValue == 0x10 || newChar.properties.rawValue == 0x8C{

            self.arrayReadWriteChar.append(newChar)

            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: newChar)
        }
        else if newChar.properties.rawValue == 0x12{

            peripheral.setNotifyValue(true, for: newChar)
        }
    }
```